# P3P Policy not working to allow 3rd party cookies in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, p3p

Thanks in advance for helping a first-time poster. I've been banging my head on the wall all day...

I have a site that must be able to function and set cookies while running inside a frame. In IE, with default security settings, this is a problem, because a framed site's cookies are treated as third party. Now, I've read all the info on P3P, and I've created a compact privacy policy, served via HTTP header, an XML policy file, and an XML reference file. I have checked, and the header is being sent properly, and IE can read the policy file.

However, it is STILL blocking cookies from the site. I've created a stripped-down example here: http://www.hankshelper.com/privtest.php
Note that cookies in the framed site are being blocked by IE (6, 7, and 8).

If anyone could check out my compact policy

```
Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR NID DEVi OUR BUS INT\""
```

and/or XML policy
http://www.searchtempest.com/w3c/searchtempest.xml

and let me know wtf, I would be eternally grateful. I've stripped them down as much as possible, and I just can't see anything that IE would have a problem with. (And of course IE itself is wonderfully verbose as far as exactly WHY it's blocking cookies...) I'm happy to provide any additional information you need.

Comment: Additional info: it appears that cookies are not blocked for some users of IE8.  For others they are.  So far it appears to be blocking cookies for all users of IE7, but my sample size is small.

Comment: did you managed solving this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain what part of our original compact policy was being rejected, but I was finally able to solve this problem with the help of couple other resources.

From here: http://www.marco.org/2007/04/27/p3p-sucks-how-to-get-frame-cookies-unblocked-in-ie6

> This is approximately the minimum HTTP header needed, and it basically
>   says “We’re not collecting any of your personal data”:
>
> P3P: CP=”NID DSP ALL COR”
>
> If you actually store some data, such as email addresses and login
>   cookies, this (also working) policy may be more correct:
>
> P3P: CP=”ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL”

The policy we ended up using was

```
ALL ADM DEV PSAo COM OUR OTRo IND ONL
```

Descriptions of all the compact policy parameters can be found here: http://www.p3pwriter.com/LRN_111.asp

Answer (score 3):

The policy checker at http://www.webentrust.com/p3p.html says `Error: No P3P Policy Found`

You are saying, in the p3p header, this:

```
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR NID DEVi OUR BUS INT"
```

meaning "I have this compact policy (CP), and also this full policy: `/w3c/p3p.xml`". BUT, http://www.hankshelper.com/w3c/p3p.xml (referenced above) gives a `404 Not Found` error. You have to create your p3p policy - e.g. using the [IBM P3P Editor](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/p3peditor) and upload it to the path you specified.

Comment: The header and policy file need to be set for the third party (ie the framed site), not the parent site.  You can find the policy reference file at http://www.searchtempest.com/w3c/p3p.xml and the policy file at http://www.searchtempest.com/w3c/searchtempest.xml

Comment: When I visit the policy checker you mentioned (http://www.webentrust.com/p3p.html) and give it the url of my privacy policy (http://hh.searchtempest.com/w3c/searchtempest.xml) it seems to work fine.  Also, thanks for the IBM link - I did use that tool to generate the policy originally.

Comment: Ah, silly me. You are right, the P3P policy has to be set for the site inside the `IFRAME`.