# P3P set header for IE8 doesn't seem to work

Tags: jsp, header, cas, p3p

The below P3P `setHeader` code is present in my CASresponse jsp but doesn't seem to work,

```
response.setHeader("P3P","policyref=\"http://sso.mydomain.net/w3c/p3p.xml\", 
CP=\"CAO IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

Am I missing something here? I am not able to get my third party cookies in IE8.

Is policref required in the header? Should i set a p3p policy for my domain?

Since its a CAS request should i set it when all requests come into CAS?? Say i have entryFilter.java should i set the P3P header there?? Or after the cookie gets created.

I am not able to retain the cookies when IE does a 302 redirect to my serviceUrl.

Comment: You can try to create a new filter, and set it as first filter in the filter chain, where to add the P3P header, as @NaMaN said

Answer (score 4):

**The short answer first :)**

you can add the header simply as

```
response.setHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

but as you need the header on all the resources, better go for the filter

```
public class P3PFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        resp.addHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

**the long answer**

I was suffering from the same issue a while back. Probably just like you, I've did my homework and developed a fair understanding of what P3P policy is and how it is meant to be used. What I was referencing at a time are

**Official links**

http://www.w3.org/P3P/

http://p3ptoolbox.com/guide/

**Notable blogs**

http://www.marco.org/2007/04/27/p3p-sucks-how-to-get-frame-cookies-unblocked-in-ie6

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/craft-a-p3p-policy-to-make-ie-behave/

**Notable SO questions**

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer?rq=1)

[P3P Policy not working to allow 3rd party cookies in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707176/p3p-policy-not-working-to-allow-3rd-party-cookies-in-ie)

despite all this I was still failing to make it work properly. What I was failing to realize, and what I eventually learned with the help of this [amazing book](http://www.manning.com/vinegar/) is that, quote

> in order to set third-party cookies for Internet Explorer users (with
>   default security settings), you need to return a special P3P HTTP
>   header with your resources that declares how your service intends to
>   employ user data. This header needs to be returned with **ALL** HTTP
>   responses for your resources, not just those that set cookies. This
>   means static resources, AJAX endpoints, iframes—everything.

I suspect that this could be your issue as well, the P3P policy I use is almost exactly the same as yours, so you're not getting denied over an invalid policy.

I set my header without a URL to a p3p policy, as said in a [techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/craft-a-p3p-policy-to-make-ie-behave/) blog

> IE does not compare the compact policy to the full-format policy, and
>   the full-format policy is not needed

and this has proven true in my tests. This would mean that you can add the header simply as

```
response.setHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

However, as you need it in all the response better write a filter something like

```
public class P3PFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        resp.addHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

and applied a filter to all requests.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>P3P Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>your.package.P3PFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>P3P Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: will try this and let u know :)

Answer (score 0):

May this helps,try modifying your code with this:

```
response.setHeader("P3P","CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT'");
```

Also have a look at this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343(v=vs.85).aspx#unsatisfactory_cookies

Answer (score 0):

Basically just write the filter like here
http://www.muneebahmad.com/index.php/archives/56
and use the

```
response.addHeader("P3P", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi
CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

then just map it to the URLs you wish to add this header or use **/*** for all.

**OR**

Here you will find almost similar question and accepted answer for the same with details sample code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121212/how-to-generate-and-deploy-p3p-privacy-policy-in-struts2-java

Hope it will help.!!